# How to operate a Kafka cluster and a streaming application 24/7 on budget?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to stream financial data (trades, orderbook) from an exchange websocket endpoint and store that data somewhere to build up my own data history for backtesting purposes. Furthermore I might want to analyze the data in real time.

I found the idea of an event driven system very interesting so that I ended up building my own dockerized confluent Kafka cluster (with avro schema-registry) and a python producer that sends the streaming data into a Kafka topic. Then I set up a Faust app to stream process the data and store it as a new topic in Kafka.

It's working fine on my laptop, but now I'm wondering how I could put this to production? Obviously I cannot do it on my laptop, because I need this application to run 24/7 without interruptions.

When I look at the fully managed Kafka cloud solutions like confluent then I find it quite expensive, especially as I'm not running a business, it's rather a private hobby project. And maybe I don't even need that kind of highly scalable and professional service.

What could be a cost efficient approach for me to get my streaming and storage application to work?
Is there another Kafka cloud solution more reduced to my needs?
Should I set up my own server? Maybe raspberry pi?
Or should I use a different approach?

I'm sorry if my problem description might not be very specific, it's a reflection of me being overwhelmed with all these system architecture questions and cloud services.

Any advice and recommendation are appreciated!

Comment: Asking for hosting solutions is considered off topic - [help]. Keywords you want to look for are "scale to zero" or "serverless kafka", which are typically considered as cheaper.

Comment: Isn’t „serverless“ kafka exactly that relatively expensive fully-managed cloud service that I mentioned?

Comment: [MSK Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/pricing/) shows 1300 per month... [Upstash](https://docs.upstash.com/kafka/pricing) is seemingly lower. Confluent Cloud might be somewhere in between, but lots of discount codes on their blog. Hosting it on your own of course costs electricity and you're already "paying" for the storage/network space through your devices and your ISP, but then you need to worry about uptime, security, etc.

Comment: IMO, I don't think you need Kafka for backtesting financial data; all of that is **historical**, not "real time", so seems like you just need a database. And if your tickers are 5-15 minutes delayed (for stocks, at least) anyway, you can just use a cron and pull the latest data. If there is ever a history-changing event like stock split/merge, then you would just overwrite the database table for those tickers. But otherwise, previous close/open prices and volume never change.

Comment: Yes, there are many options, I was even considering to buy a very efficient hardware (e.g. raspberry pi?) that should be perfectly reduced for this kind of task (minimum electricity). Of course I have to manage uptime... I cannot estimate atm how difficult that is...

Comment: I decided for an event driven system, because I want to be able to analyse real time changes of market data.

Comment: Polling a websocket is "real time changes". You dont necessarily need a message broker for that. However, NATS or RedPanda takes far less resources than Kafka would if you are only limited to a Raspberry Pi.